# Can a REST service be used by both active and passive clients?

Tags: rest, wif

I have a Silverlight application that calls a REST service.  I want to enable single sign on with another website so I'm inclined to implement passive authentication.  When the browser navigates to the XAP file, it will get redirected to the STS.  After presenting credentials, the browser downloads the XAP file.

At this point the browser has 2 cookies: 1 identifying a session with the STS and 1 indicating a session with the RP that hosted the XAP file.  All HTTP traffic generated by the Silverlight app goes through the browser so the STS session cookie is automatically included outgoing requests even though I don't have direct access to it.  The other website trusts the same STS so it respects the existing STS session and everything's grand.

But now I want to implement an iOS client which will probably be active.  Can this client consume the same REST services, and if so, how?